# Trying to use async method TextReader.ReadBlockAsync, but getting "the 'await' operator can only be used within an async method"

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I want to call the asynchronous reader method of `TextReader`, but always get a compile error:

```
var buffer = new char[10];

TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\temp\abc.txt");

// the following statement will get compile error
var readCount = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

This is the error:

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. 
>     Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

What is the right way to use `ReadBlockAsync`?

Comment: Have you considered marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: Seriously. I mean, it's hard to think of how much clearer the error message could be, not only in terms of what's wrong, but how to fix it! If you need more help than what the error message is already giving you, you need to explain that in specific detail. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to mark the method with the `async` identifier as mentioned by others. The method then needs to return a `Task`, `Task<T>` or `void`. However `void` returning async methods are reserved for async event handlers. So in your case you'd probably want to return a `Task<string>`

```
public async Task<string> ReadAsync()
{
    var buffer = new char[10];

    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(@"D:\temp\abc.txt");

    var readCount = await reader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  

    return new string(buffer.Take(readCount).ToArray());
}
```

You may find the following resources useful: [Best practices with Async/Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx), [Asynchronous Programming with Async-Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: You've left in the line "the following statement will get compile error"